# addClass/removeClass after AJAX call

Tags: ajax, shopify, addclass, removeclass, pushstate

I have a navigation that loads content into a specific element on the page via AJAX:

```
<ul class="main-nav-child">
    <li><a href="/collections/page1">page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/collections/page2">page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/collections/page3">page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

The following snippet makes that happen:

```
$('ul.main-nav-child a').bind('click', function(e) {           
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $(".main-content").load(url + " .product-grid-collection");
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the browser from following the link
});
```

My question is this: How can I update the URL in the browser to reflect the link that's been clicked  and also `addClass` of .active to that link (and `removeClass` from the previous active link), without refreshing the page?

**UPDATE**: So I've now managed to get the URL to change when a link's clicked, I just need to `addClass` of .active to each link when clicked and `removeClass` .active for the previous link.

Here's my updated code:

```
$('ul.main-nav-child a').bind('click', function(e) {           
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $(".main-content").load(url + " .product-grid-collection");
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the browser from following the link
        var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
        history.pushState(stateObj, "", url);
});
```

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your required output is not quite clear to me. You are probably looking for `window.location.hash` and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607480/jquery-add-active-class-to-main-menu. A fiddle would be a good start.

Comment: @GauravBhor I've solved part of the question by using `pushState`, the URL now updates without refreshing the browser, now I'm trying to add a class of .active to a link when clicked, and remove that class when another link is clicked, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Check the link I gave you. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @GauravBhor Yes I'm checking the link, and yes, I think it could help me, thank you, I'll update here if if works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are looking for "replace with" in conjunction with hijacking links
[jQuery: hijack a link and find its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515685/jquery-hijack-a-link-and-find-its-parent)

this will take a link replace your current html page with out reloading and then you can add the link to your custom pushstate array giving you the appearance of a one page application